# When should you close a scanner?

Tags: java, string, character, java.util.scanner

I've been trying to read input from a file and classifying its characters. Printing how  many characters are uppercase letters, lowercase letters, digits, white space, and something else in the text file. So I've been working at my code, but I ran into two problems.

When I try to close my scanner I run into a java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed. Additionally, my code produces an endless loop, but I've been looking at it for hours but I don't know what's wrong. I'm a beginner at Java so I haven't learned about hashmap or Buffered Readers yet. Thank you for all your help.

Here is my code:

```
 import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Characters
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Input file: ");
      String inputFileName = console.next();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName)); 

      while(in.hasNextLine())
      {
          String line = in.nextLine(); 
          int len = line.length(); 
          int uppercase = 0 ;
          int lowercase = 0;
          int digits = 0;
          int whitespace = 0; 
          int other = 0; 

          for ( int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
          {
              char c = line.charAt(i); 

          if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
          {
              lowercase++; 
          }
          else if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
          {
              uppercase++;
          }
          else if (Character.isDigit(c))
          {
              digits++; 
          }
          else if (Character.isWhitespace(c))
          {
              whitespace++;
          }
          else
              other++;
          }

      System.out.println("Uppercase: " + uppercase);
      System.out.println("Lowercase: " + lowercase);
      System.out.println("Digits: " + digits);
      System.out.println("Whitespace: " + whitespace);
      System.out.println("Other: " + other);
      in.close();

   }


   }
}
```

Comment: suppose you move the `in.close()` out side the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should close Scanner out of the `while` loop by using try-with-resouces.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Characters {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input file: ");
        String inputFileName = console.next();
        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName))) {
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                int len = line.length();
                int uppercase = 0;
                int lowercase = 0;
                int digits = 0;
                int whitespace = 0;
                int other = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    char c = line.charAt(i);

                    if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                        lowercase++;
                    } else if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                        uppercase++;
                    } else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        digits++;
                    } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                        whitespace++;
                    } else
                        other++;
                }

                System.out.println("Uppercase: " + uppercase);
                System.out.println("Lowercase: " + lowercase);
                System.out.println("Digits: " + digits);
                System.out.println("Whitespace: " + whitespace);
                System.out.println("Other: " + other);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are try-with-resources things like BufferedReader?

Comment: Yes. `Scanner` is closed by try-with-resouces because it implements `Closeable`.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the Scanner after you're done using it. That sample has you closing at the end of the loop, so it tries to check for more data in the while condition and fails.

Try moving the close till after the while loop has exited.

Comment: I've tried closing the scanner outside the while loop  but then I get an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are closing the scanner in your **while** loop. You have to close it outside the loop. You get the exception because after the first loop iteration the scanner is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to perform search operations after a scanner has been closed will result in an IllegalStateException.
You are closing the scanner right after the first iteration ( after the first line is read)

Moving the close() method outside of the while-loop will solve the problem.